# How to separate details section with diffrent headers in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want crystal report should be like this

### container   size

container1   20
container2   30

### Charges   rate

BL       10
Bl       20

but while creating it gets mixed up how seoarate out details and headers

Answer (score 0):

Just add more detail sections. Detail section a will have your header "Container Size" then section b will have your fields... section c will have "Charges Rate" header and section d the detail.